# How do we know how many popups are open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application, window opened pop1, pop1 opened pop2 and pop2 opened pop3. I am in pop3. How i know how many windows/popups opened before pop3 in jquery or javascript

Comment: `window.opener.opener.opener... ` until opener is null or undefined

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: What's the relation? This is a good question.

Comment: If you have that many popups, methinks I'll be avoiding your site.  However, +1 for asking an interesting question.

Comment: @Randy the point of this was not the quality of the question, but the fact that users are not enticed to answer a question if they don't see a chance to gain anything from it.

Comment: @Richard: It's not like (s)he begged for an answer. And the question is very recent: it's not like nobody is willing to answer. We don't know that yet. Your comment would be more applicable if the question was open for multiple days. ;-)

Comment: @vishnu: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Comment: @Richard and four of those accepts are to his own questions...

Comment: @levu I think this window.opener works if we are in pop1. I am getting null on first shot only. How can we do reverse?Thank you

Comment: @Richard Thank you. Initially i accepted exact answers only. Now i accepted relavive answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. It might helpful for any one who looking for the answer. In below code `count` will give the answer to find the no of windows to open.

```
popup = this;count=0;
if(window.top != popup.self)
{
 count=count+1;
 popup = popup.parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming:**

- Your use of the words window/popups you mean ['modal dialogs'](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
- They all have the same class that is only used by modals. *(I'll use `.ui-dialog` in my example)*
- This give the amount of modals that are currently open, *not how many **were** opened*.

`var modalsCurrentlyOpen = $('.ui-dialog').length;`

Comment: I wouldn't assume window/popups == modal dialogs, ie `window.open()` doesn't assume the window opened is a modal dialog.

Comment: They did mark it jQuery - seems logical. Further, using `window.open()` is a bad idea anyway.  It's a usability no-no.

Comment: @Levi Yes. I am using ui-dialog only. How it differs the amont of modals and how many. This length also returning the modals opened in that window not about their parent windows. Thank you.

Comment: @mrk i think i may used words incorrectly. I have used modal dialogs only.

Comment: @vishnu Could you explain: 'This length also returning the modals opened in that window not about their parent windows. Thank you.'  Are you talking LITERALLY windows, or are we talking dialogs?

Comment: '$('.ui-dialog').length' returning the no of modal dialogues opened in that window. In my example, if i am in pop2, then this code returns 1 as pop3 opened from pop2. But i want length for modal dialogues opened before pop2. I have reread your answer. I think you are saying the same. Do you have any idea how to back track.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps initialize a counter variable and then add one to it anytime `window.open` is run. 
But then 
a)you'd need to send a vairable to parent window when open popup is closed (probably using a hidden field value)  something like this on unload:
opener.document.your_form.counter.value ++;
b) If user have popup blocker that's not gonna work.